# check preg_match_all for string and guid

Tags: php, regex

I writing `preg_match_all` which test for match on string. It is working for for normal string and numeric values but when I pass GUID it fail.

`/{([\w\-_]*[\w]{1})\(?([\w,]*)?\)?([+,])?([a-zA-Z]*)?\(?([\w\/]*)?([\-,])?([\w\/]*)?\)?}/`

Data which pass is
`{abc_test(1))}`

What I want to be pass is
`{abc_test(1))}` and `{abc_test(2dc7ba10-fe29-4de6-9282-a4ebc5eee87d))}`

`{abc_test(2dc7ba10-fe29-4de6-9282-a4ebc5eee87d))}`will always have `GUID`.

Comment: I don't know how you are specifically using this beyond just a GUID, but you should be able to use `/{(?<function>[\w]*)(?<open_paren>\()(?<contents>[\w-]+)(?<close_paren>\))}/` which you can see here: https://regex101.com/r/i4Onmb/1. Even if you don't use the named parameters, it really helps to see them for debugging purposes. Also, your sample on the last line appears to have two closing `)` unless that it expected.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes about the pattern:

- There are some capture groups that can be omitted from the pattern
- Using `([\w\/]*)?` can be written as `[\w\/]*` because the character class is already optionally repeated
- You can omit `{1}` and if you move the `-` in the character class to the end you don't have to escape it
- Using `\w` will also match `_` so that can be omitted as well
- Almost all the parts (except for the beginning of the pattern) are optional which can make it very inefficient with all the optional to backtrack to looking for a match

Without the superfluous parts, the pattern will look like:

```
{([\w-]*\w)\(?[\w,]*\)?([+,])?([a-zA-Z]*)?\(?[\w/]*([,-])?[\w/]*\)?}
```

The GUID parts does not match because at the end of the pattern this part `[\w/]*([,-])?[\w/]*` can match only a single occurrence of `-` while the GUID contains multiple occurrences.

---

An example pattern to match the gives example strings without capture groups, could be matching either word characters or a pattern that matches the chars that can occur in the GUID separated by a hyphen.

Note that the example strings have a single `(` and `))` at the end

```
{\w+(?:-\w+)*\((?:[a-fA-F0-9]+(?:-[a-fA-F0-9]+)+|\w+)\)+}
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `{` Match the opening `{`
- `\w+(?:-\w+)*` Match 1+ word chars, optionally repeated by `-` and 1+ word chars
- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation `|`

  - `[a-fA-F0-9]+(?:-[a-fA-F0-9]+)+`
  - `|` Or
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\)+` Match 1+ closing parenthesis
- `}` Match the closing `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gWm5oL/1)